# MySQL user is not expired but asking for Password RESET

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am getting the below error for the user **root@'%'**, but when I login through **root@'localhost'**,I can see the **password_expired = 'N' for root@'%'**

Server version:         5.7.9-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

> ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER
>   statement before executing this statement.

```
+------+------+------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| user | host | password_expired | account_locked | password_lifetime | password_last_changed |
+------+------+------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| root | %    | N                | N              |              NULL | 2015-12-16 04:50:23   |
+------+------+------------------+----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The password *is* expired -- implicitly -- after 360 days -- in MySQL Server 5.7 versions prior to 5.7.11.

> From MySQL 5.7.4 to 5.7.10, the default [`default_password_lifetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_password_lifetime)  value is 360 (passwords must be changed approximately once per year). For those versions, be aware that, if you make no changes to the `default_password_lifetime` variable or to individual user accounts, all user passwords will expire after 360 days, and all user accounts will start running in restricted mode when this happens. Clients (which are effectively users) connecting to the server will then get an error indicating that the password must be changed: `ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before executing this statement.`
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html

Temporary workaround *should* be this:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL DEFAULT_PASSWORD_LIFETIME = 0;
```

Better, add to the `mysqld` section of `my.cnf`:

```
default_password_lifetime = 0
```

...or another appropriate value for your site, then restart the server.

Even better still... upgrade.  There were numerous bugs in early GA versions of 5.7, particularly 5.7.9, which was the first GA version of the release series.

Of course, you *should* be able to modify this account using [`ALTER USER ... PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html) which is apparently not the same as the `NULL` value shown in the table.

Comment: Thanks Michael...I understand that it is expired..but why it still shows 'N' instead of 'Y' on mysql.user table's password_expired column?

Comment: That column is only used to **force** a password to *appear* to be expired, requiring a password change on next login.  `ALTER USER ... PASSWORD EXPIRE;` would be the way that column gets set to `'Y'`. [*"The `password_expired` column permits DBAs to expire account passwords and require users to reset their password."*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-tables.html)